# Change the page after an action is done

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios4

I have 2 pages with xib files. One is a login page and the other is a welcome page.

Here is the login function:

```
-(IBAction)login{
NSLog(@"login begin");

NSString *loginResponse = [self tryLogin];
NSLog(@"%@", loginResponse);

loginError.text = loginResponse;


    NSUserDefaults *session = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [session setInteger:1 forKey:@"islogged"];
}
```

After the user is logged in successfully I need to redirect them to another xib file which is called Notifications. Now how exactly should I do this?

Also for some reason when I put an if statement inside the function, it doesnt go into the statements.

```
-(IBAction)login{
NSLog(@"login begin");

NSString *loginResponse = [self tryLogin];
NSLog(@"%@", loginResponse);


if(responseInt == @"2"){
    NSLog(@"login error 2");

    UIAlertView *alertURL = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error!" 
                                                       message:@"Username or password is wrong!"
                                                      delegate:nil 
                                             cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" 
                                             otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [alertURL show];
    [alertURL release];
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////
}else if(responseInt == @"0"){
    NSUserDefaults *session = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [session setInteger:1 forKey:@"islogged"];

}

}
```

As you can see I try to nslog something as soon as one of the conditions are met but it does not go into any of the statements (the loginResponse is sent back as 2).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**How to change views**

If you app is navigation-based then you can add new fullscreen views using method `[self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];`.

Everywhere you can add new fullscreen view using next method : `[self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];`.

**Issue with 'if-statement'.**

When you want to compare to objects you should use one of following methods:

1. `compare:`, this method return one of following values: `NSOrderedSame`, `NSOrderedDescending`, `NSOrderedAscending`. For example, `if ([responseInt compare:@"2"] == NSOrderedSame) {// equal}`
2. 'isEqual:', for example, `if ([responseInt isEqual:@"2"]) {// equal}`
3. or some specific comparators for concrete class

Don't forget that when you are comparing using `==` or `>` and etc you are comparing addresses of objects in memory.

Comment: ahh thank you so much :) I am used to programming in js and php :) any thoughts about the first issue regarding redirecting users from one page to another?

Comment: I know this sounds stupid but I am having difficulty declaring the controller, how exactly are you suppose to do that?

Comment: Create new `UIViewController` using `Add new files...` in Xcode, check to create `.xib` file with this controller and that's all

Comment: yea I have done that, but to redirect the page to a new UIViewController here is what I am doing : 
include the class of the other UIViewController in the header file of the page I need to be redirected : 
    `@class Notifications`
and create a new IBOutlet like : 

   `@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet Login *controller;`

and then putting the following code in the .m file : 
   `@synthesize controller;`

and then using your code like : 

        `[self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];`


but it still gives me an error!!!

Comment: I think you should create another one question and post code and error there.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried doing isEqualToString:  instead of the equal sign?  That is a more reliable string comparator.   Also it seems strange that your login method is returning a string and not an integer.  Is there a reason for that?

Comment: no there is not really a reason for it... can you help me out with the problem of changing UIViews?? if you read my last comment on the answer above you would know what the problem is... thanks